# How to compress a 160 char person_ID in oracle DB which is limited to 25 char AND maintain uniqueness?

Tags: oracle, identifier

Is it possible to compress an alphanumeric 160 char unique ID to 25 char to be used as a unique identifier in Oracle DB?

thank you!

Seeking advice as I cannot even start to understand how to attack this issue

Comment: Perhaps use the DBMS_CRYPTO package to produce a checksum?

Comment: Cast the varchar2 to raw (utl_raw.cast_to_raw), then dbms_crypto.hash that with hash_sh1 algorithm will give you a 20 byte raw output.

Comment: Simple answer: no, it is not possible. You can create a hash value or check sum but this will be only **likely** unique, you cannot guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: You may create additional table that uses sequence and maps `char(160)` to number that may be limited by 25 decimal places. While theoretically your task may look impossible, semantically you unlikely to have 10^25 persons - it's more than the number of people that had ever lived on Earth

Comment: Thank you all.. I appreciate your input. Even though @WernfriedDomscheit is right, I'll try Paul W suggestion for the mental exercise. 

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you @BobC. I have an external identifier which I'd like to store in the SBR/OHMPI. the external identifier is a possible 160 character long and field in OHMPI is 25 max

Comment: What is SBR/OHMPI? Having said that, why not store it as 160 chars in Oracle?